# IntelliJ Remove code with the same "name"

Tags: intellij-idea

there was an option in IntelliJ to remove code with the same name f.x everything that starts with _ngBlabla I dont remember how to do it maybe someone can help.
Thx
Felix

Answer (score 0):

For all project files:

In the **Project** window (left hand side). Press Ctrl + Shift + R (⌘ + ⇧ + R on Mac), or right click **Replace in Files**. Then just find `_ngBlabla` and replace with an empty string.

For all instances in one file there are two ways:

1. Find and Replace (same instructions as above without the ⇧ Key)
2. Highlight and press Ctrl + F (⌘ + F) and click **Select All Occurrences**. This will create multiple carats at each position where that occurs and you can modify from there

Personally I use the **Select All Occurrences** so much that I added it to the keymap.